# call procedure via dblink

Tags: oracle, plsql

below is a source of my procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure SYS.ChangePassword(
  pUsername in varchar2, 
  pNewPassword in varchar2,
  pResult out varchar2)  as
  **pragma autonomous_transaction;**
begin
    insert into test_table values( to_date(sysdate), pUsername, pNewPassword);
    **commit;**
    execute immediate 'alter user '||pUsername||' identified by "'|| pNewPassword || '"';
    pResult := 'New password for '|| pUsername||' has been set:  '|| pNewPassword ;
exception
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    pResult := SQLERRM;
end;
```

nothing special, it just set a new password to user. It works as I expect - returns info about new password

```
New password for TEST_user has been set:  XSW1!WDC1
```

or returns error message

```
ORA-28003: password verification for the specified password failed
ORA-20004: Password should contain at least one digit, one character and one punctuation
```

And of course it adds a record to test table.

The point is how to call this procedure from other database using dblink.
When I do it in a way as below:

```
DECLARE
   vResult varchar2(400);
BEGIN
   ChangePassword@db23('TEST_USER','XS21345W1!WDC1',vResult );
   commit;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(vResult);
END;
```

it returns no errors but neither new record to table is added nor message about success/error appears.

solution:  adding pragma at the begging of procedure "changes the way a subprogram works within a transaction".

Comment: Even if this Procedure's execution has been granted to the caller's Schema/User_Name, it should authenticate through the DEFINER rights, that is SYS. Not really sure if it would work, but put `AUTHID DEFINER` in the Procedure definition.

Comment: @g00dy AUTHID DEFINER is default value as far as I know

Comment: If you have `grant execute` to a certain user, that IS the case and they are equal as authid definer. Btw, you don't need a commit, as the procedure has a DML, followed by a DDL, which does an implicit commit. TRy putting an arbitrary value in `pResult := SQLERRM;`, instead of `SQLERRM` to see if you enter the exception block, something like 'Exception raised.'. Or try throwing a real exception there.

Comment: google helped !   adding **autonomous_transaction** pragma solved the problem

Comment: I would suggest you to better describe it, as now its not clear at all why this `PRAGMA` actually solved it.

Comment: Interesting. Definig it as an autonomous transaction causes the logic to run in it's own transaction. Meaning it's not running within the distributed transaction, which you normally have when using dblinks.

Comment: When you did not use autonomous transactions: did you do a commit after calling your procedure? Here's something more on the topic: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:362818006460